# How to get the checked items in checklistbox

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, checklistbox

I have a checklistbox and the items of it came from my database (tbl_Section) so it loads all the Section Number (Primary Key). I have 5 Section Numbers, and 3 of it will be assigned to only one teacher. I'm thinking of using While-statement but i dont know how.

To make it simpler to you, this is what i need to do:

```
While //index(number) is checked
      //do something
Else (i know it should not be ELSE, but i dont know what keyword is to be used)
      //do something
End While
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure `While` is what you're after. If you want to loop through your records you could look at `For Each` Then within these statements use `If Checked...Else`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is iterate through every item in your checkbox. For each item, you check if it is checked, then you act accordingly :

```
'We will run through each indice
For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    'You can replace As Object by your object type
    'ex : Dim Item As String = CType(CheckedListBox1.Items(i), String)
    Dim Item As Object = CheckedListBox1.Items(i)

    'We ask if this item is checked or not
    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) Then
        'Do something if Item is checked
    Else
        'Do something else if Item is not checked
    End If
Next
```

Comment: does the variable 'item' refers to the value of the checked item in checkedlistbox?

Comment: @ABCDE it is the item in the list

Comment: how can i get the value (text) of the checked item? because i need to transfer the text to the database...

Comment: What type are the items in your checkedlistbox ? Strings ? Other objects ?

Comment: they are strings sir

Comment: @ABCDE Then use the commented example line (`Dim Item as String...`), your items will be strings and you can use them directly.

Comment: ahh yes, sorry i didnt notice. thanks a lot! big help!

Comment: @ABCDE if this answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted, so next users with the same problem will quickly find an answer.